# How can I know who has voted down my question?

Tags: support, downvotes, voting

In last 5 minutes somebody voted down my two questions I asked earlier on Stack Overflow.
*Can I know who is that person who voted down my questions?* Because he has mentioned no reason for that.

Comment: No, you can't know that. Which means you can't know that one person downvoted two of your questions - all you know is that you received two downvotes.

Comment: Thanks Rapptz, Jon Skeet and Cupcake for your quick response.

Comment: There is no obligation for a down voter to ever give a reason.

Comment: @slugster but its not good that somebody come to your profile and start downvoting all your questions.

Comment: @Himanshu you ***assume*** that a single user has gone through your profile and downvoted all of your questions.

Comment: @Cupcake yes I think like so. I might be wrong.

Comment: @Himanshu Serial (revenge) downvotes will be rolled back automatically within 24 hrs. If this doesn't apply, you may flag one of these questions for moderator attention, and leave a comment what you think was going wrong.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanx for giving knowledge on this topic.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not sure if that's the best thing to do. I've heard that mods can't do anything if there was no serial downvote reversal event, and that you might just be wasting their time if you flag in such a case. But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Cupcake May be questionable that 2 downvotes count as a serial downvote. But if some user was _"intelligent"_ enough, to leave some time between downvotes, it might be missed by the standard mechanism. At least a moderator can contact that user, and ask for clarification. That once happened to me, when I was downvoting a number of poorly asked questions of a particular user. I'm not sure, but believe a mod can rollback downvotes manually.

Comment: Sometimes they comment on your question when they downvote to point out the flaw in your question, E.G.:  "it's unclear", I hope it helped :) +1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't know who downvoted your question, unless the person chooses to reveal him/herself.  That's intentional.

However, if someone is serially downvoting your questions (goes through and downvotes several of yours in a row), it will eventually be reversed by the automatic processes.  How many votes exactly define 'serial' is intentionally unknown.

Comment: ok, thanx @joe for your answer and providing some knowledge regarding this.