# How many votes can a serial voter vote before a serial voter's votes are counted as serial?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

According to [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266486/510036), the number of serial votes a serial voter must vote before the system identifies them as a serial voter is 'unknown'.

Is there any clarification? Is there a formula? Or are the serial voting gods atypical and bring in time as a factor?

**What is the definitive equation of serial votes necessary before it is considered *serial*?**

Comment: Yes, there's a formula, but it's secret to prevent people from gaming it.

Comment: @Mysticial Oh, right, the whole [ob]s[e]curity thing. :|

Comment: "How many votes" is grammatically correct, vs "How much votes". Though it breaks your wood-chuck theme, I replaced "voted" with "counted", since the system doesn't "vote" on votes.

Comment: Yeah, they don't want you to know, otherwise a serial voter could vote just one less than the number of votes they can vote before their votes are voted as serial. I think this has been discussed before, so the up vote is just for the question title that made me laugh. :)

Comment: @Cupcake I tried, okay? :|

Comment: @Cupcake Spoilsport :p

Comment: @gnat sure enough; `serial` wasn't doing me any good, it seems.

Comment: I love the title of this question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there is no clarification. Stack Exchange **doesn't want** there to be clarification because it makes it easier to game the system. There is an algorithm that detects it so it can be reversed automatically and the staff can manually reverse votes after investigation. That's all the information you're ever going to get on this matter.